# Unknown Column name in field list (case)- MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am struggling on query mysql database. The following is an exemplification of my entire much longer query:

```
SELECT * ,


CASE WHEN t1.route = NULL THEN NULL ELSE left(t1.route,4) END AS node1,

CASE WHEN node1 = NULL THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(node1) = CHAR_LENGTH(route) THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(route,6,4) END END AS node2


FROM (SELECT *, [...] FROM main_db) t1;
```

When I run it on mysql workbench, this error appears:

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'node1' in 'field list'`

I noticed that my code is qorking perfectly on TSQL database but not on MYSQL and I think the problem is that after each action performed by the mysql, it doens't update the column list and so, I can't query from a column created in the same statement.

I previously tackled down this kind of problem by nesting queries in another queries but since I don't want to have more or less 14/16 nested queries, I am looking an efficient way to solve my problem.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The column alias node1 isn't in scope in the same select list as it is defined. You need a derived table (subquery)!

Comment: `CASE WHEN t1.route = NULL THEN NULL ELSE left(t1.route,4) END AS node1,` can be simplified as `left(t1.route,4) AS node1`.

Comment: @jarlh good point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

col`=null` checking is not possible you need `is null` so it would be like below for checking part

```
SELECT * ,   

CASE WHEN t1.route is NULL THEN NULL ELSE left(t1.route,4) END AS node1,
```

and node1 is column can not use here in line

you can use subquery for that

Comment: Sorry but I haven't write =null. My query is syntax error free

Comment: @LucaFerrario col=null is checking is not possible as null undefined value

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` expression is not doing anything useful -- even if you use `is null` correctly.

Just do:

```
SELECT t1.* ,
       LEFT(t1.route, 4) as node1,
       (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(LEFT(t1.route, 4)) <> CHAR_LENGTH(route)
             THEN SUBSTRING(route, 6, 4) 
        END) AS node2
FROM (SELECT *, [...] FROM main_db) t1;
```

You cannot re-use the column alias in the same `SELECT`.

If you do want to re-use it, then move the logic to the subquery:

```
SELECT t1.* ,
       (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(node1) <> CHAR_LENGTH(route)
             THEN SUBSTRING(route, 6, 4) 
        END) AS node2
FROM (SELECT *, [...],
             LEFT(t1.route, 4) as node1,
      FROM main_db
     ) t1;
```